# How do I stop my terminal from clearing when attaching a screen?

Tags: bash, debian, gnu-screen

On my previous Debian server, I would be able to attach a screen, detach and then see the previous terminal I was working on. The buffer would still be there.

Now, when I attach a screen on my new server, the previous terminal buffer will disappear.

"clear" is being ran either pre-attachment or post-detachment of a screen, and it looks like a fresh terminal. I would like to keep the terminal in its previous state, such as after leaving a text editor like nano or vim.

Additional info: using the terminal "xterm," have tried xterm-256color (where a friend successfully solves this problem,) and vt100.

Comment: Can't replicate. Tried Deb local and Deb remote over SSH. Have you tried root or a new user in the terminal (would limit to customisations in .bashrc and .profile as the problem)